# How to write Locust result of test api to file

Tags: python, python-2.7, locust

I invoke the test through API,

```
locust -f locustfile.py --host=http://localhost --no-web  --hatch-rate=20 --clients=10000
```

and got a result

```
 Name                                                          # reqs      # fails     Avg     Min     Max  |  Median   req/s
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 POST 8000/queries.json                                           137     0(0.00%)       5       2      23  |       5   11.00

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Total                                                            708     0(0.00%)
```

I would like to write this result to a file. Can anyone help me with this?

Below is the code in python

```
@task(1)
def test_topview(self):
    post_data_topview = """{ "category": "321",   "num": 20,   "genderCat" : ["23"] }"""
    with self.client.request(method="POST", url="http://192.168.1.107:8001/queries.json", headers= {"Content-Type" : "application/json"}, data = post_data_topview, catch_response = True ) as response:
        if not matched(response.content) :
            response.failure("No content")
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option until the statsfile option is live would be to redirect stderr to an output file, which apparently is where the stats are logged to:

```
 locust -f locustfile.py --host=http://example.com --no-web --clients=20  --hatch-rate=20 --num-request=1000  --only-summary  > locust.log   2>&1
```

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATE**

Saving csv file with the option `--csv` is added with this [release](https://github.com/locustio/locust/releases/tag/v0.8a3) . So you can run the following command to save result of the test as `foo_requests.csv` and `foo_distribution.csv`

```
locust -f locustfile.py --host=http://localhost --no-web  --hatch-rate=20 --clients=10000 --only-summary --csv=foo
```

**FOR the version below 0.8**

There has been a commit for saving the result of Locust but it is not merged to Locust yet. However you can update it manually with [this commit](https://github.com/locustio/locust/pull/291/files). It is adding a new parameters as `--statsfile=result.log` to save the result.

Then the complete command should look like this

```
locust -f locustfile.py --host=http://localhost --no-web  --hatch-rate=20 --clients=10000 --only-summary --statsfile=result.log
```

You can check [this post](http://www.testrisk.com/2016/01/performance-testing-on-ci-integration.html) for updating Locust and checking the result of the log.

Comment: Dear Mesut, which version of locust are you using? I used 'easy_install locustio pyzmq' and got the version 0.7.3. Seem that this version does not have --statsfile option.  Thanks!

Comment: @LeKimTrang I have same version. The commit didnt merged to Locust so you can not use `--statsfile` however you can update your local files as in mentioned in the blog post.

Answer (score 4):

I have tried to print locust stats in a file without success, but you can do it in using **event hook** : http://docs.locust.io/en/latest/api.html#available-hooks.

You can add a function to the event request_success and request_failure, so each time a request success or fail your hook function will be called in order to get request data into a list or any variable you want.

Then you can easily print the data into a csv file for instance

Hope it would help you

```
import locust.events
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet


class LocustUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = TaskSet
    min_wait = 1000
    max_wait = 1000

    request_success_stats = [list()]
    request_fail_stats = [list()]

    def __init__(self):
        locust.events.request_success += self.hook_request_success
        locust.events.request_failure += self.hook_request_fail
        locust.events.quitting += self.hook_locust_quit

    def hook_request_success(self, request_type, name, response_time, response_length):
        self.request_success_stats.append([name, request_type, response_time])

    def hook_request_fail(self, request_type, name, response_time, exception):
        self.request_fail_stats.append([name, request_type, response_time, exception])

    def hook_locust_quit(self):
        self.save_success_stats()

    def save_success_stats(self):
        import csv
        with open('success_req_stats.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
            for value in self.request_success_stats:
                writer.writerow(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to Rays answer from 2016.
In the current locust version 1.0.3 you'll need to add the event listeners like this

```
events.request_success.add_listener(self.hook_request_success)
```

instead of using +=

I used this to aggregate and write the responses into a database for further analysis

Answer (score 0):

locust -f loustfile.py -c 1 -r 1 -n 100 --host=http://localhost:4000 --no-web --only-summary > ../result/locustTest.log 2>&1